# OpenShift git push master does not change application

Tags: openshift

I can push and pull to my master branch of my openshift app, but it does not change from the 'Welcome To ...", how do I make my changes active? I'm just starting out making my first app, (and making changes) with an index.html node.js app that works locally.  It is still the page: "Welcome to your Node.js application on OpenShift".  My git push works because I can pull the changes to another folder repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
$ rhc app-restart -a $APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a static file that is served on behalf of your application and rename it.
I found that error as I had an index.html that was being served as an static file instead of being rooted through the applications